# SQL - Select multiple users from a table asoiciated with multiple options AKA Relations division

Tags: mysql, sql, select

The problem is that I have a table where users have certain options "active" this is a representation of the table:

```
USER | OPTION
-------------
1    | A
1    | B
1    | C
2    | A
2    | D
2    | E
3    | A
3    | D
3    | M
```

let's assume we would like to select only those users that have both option `A` AND `D` (users 2 and 3 in this case).

I have thought something like nested `SELECT`, but I would like something that I could build with a loop, in fact `OPTION` will have about 40 distinct values and this query should be built with a form on the page.

any ideas?
unluckily the database "is done like this" and can not be changed (minor changes could be done, like add another field, but I can't change the logic behind)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> select only those users that have both option A AND D

It is called [*relation division*](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/), here is one way to do so:

```
SELECT `user`
FROM tablename 
WHERE `option` in ('A', 'D')
GROUP BY `user`
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `option`) = 2;
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7ab2/2)

Comment: awesome, I have learned a new thing, thanks, i'll search ASAP for relation division! :D
I'll test this and accept the answer